# How to return the values of a factor that have a 0 level as the raw numbers

Tags: r, type-conversion, factors

I am using a model to create prediction.  The model is giving me a factor out which ranges from 0 to 6.

I am trying to report this as this value, but when I try to convert this to a number or put it into a data frame, it converts the 0 value to a 1 and all the other values up one...sometimes.

> out = as.factor(c(0,1,2,3,4,5))
> out
> [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5
> Levels: 0 1 2 3 4 5

> as.numeric(out)
> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

I would simply subtract by 1 if this increased the value by 1 everytime, but if my model returns only non-zero values, it will not increase the value:

> out = as.factor(c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
> as.numeric(out)
> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

Is there a simple way to get the raw values out of the factor rather than R converting the 0 to a 1 and adjusting the rest of the values?

Thank you,

RStudio 1.3.1093
r 4.0.3

Comment: `as.numeric(as.character(out))`. Without the `as.char` part, it's returning the number of the integer indices; see `as.numeric(factor(c('a','1')))` versus `as.numeric(as.character(factor(c('a','1'))))` (which should emit a warning).

Comment: You should note from this that *"get the raw values ... and adjusting the rest of the values"* is a risky proposition: if everything is 0-based and everything is in the right order and nothing it *gapped*, then this might be safe ... if any of those conditions is not met, however, then you will silently corrupt your data.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information

Answer (score 1):

From my own comments, I found the solution here:  [How to convert a factor to integer\numeric without loss of information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information)

"In particular, as.numeric applied to a factor is meaningless, and may happen by implicit coercion. To transform a factor f to approximately its original numeric values, as.numeric(levels(f))[f] is recommended and slightly more efficient than as.numeric(as.character(f))." - [Joshua Ulrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271616/joshua-ulrich)

This solved the issue and I was able to put into a data frame without a problem.